# Tkinter method deiconify seems not working on ubuntu(12.04, unity)

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

Tkinter method "deiconify" seems not working on ubuntu(12.04, unity), but the the following code works as expected on windows 7. I need to show the window even it is minimized when something happens in another project https://github.com/thinker3/youdao.

```
from time import sleep
from Tkinter import Tk

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Test")
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_handler)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def close_handler(self):
        self.root.iconify()
        sleep(1)
        self.root.deiconify()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = GUI()
```

Comment: your code has seemingly nothing to do with being minimized. All you're doing is showing the (only) window when the user tries to destroy it. Plus, your `close_handler` will likely appear to do nothing since you don't allow the event loop to update the screen before it completes.

Comment: @BryanOakley: self.root.iconify() minimizes the window. This is a simplified example I made, especially to see some differences between windows7 and ubuntu when running it.

Comment: you minimize, then you _freeze the program_ for one second, then deiconify it. You'll never see it minimized because the GUI is frozen. The event loop needs to run in order for the window to be removed from the screen.

Comment: @BryanOakley: on windows7, when closing it, i see it minimized to the taskbar, 1 second later, show again. on ubuntu, it does not show again, except i click the icon on the launcher

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is apparently the difference between Windows and non-Windows. It looks to me like the Windows behavior is a bug. At the very least, it's not expected behavior. What you are seeing on ubuntu is what I would expect to see.

For a GUI to do anything, the event loop must be running. *Everything* that happens is the response to an event. The drawing of a window on the screen is a response to an event. A button click is a response to an event. The visual effect of a button being pressed is a response to an event. And so on.

When you call `iconify`, that causes an event to be sent to the app saying "remove the window from the screen". The event loop sees the event, and redraws (or "un"draws) the window. The reverse happens when you call `deiconify` -- the system gets a redraw event, and tkinter redraws the window on the screen.

In your code, you never give the event loop a chance to respond to these events. You ask it to iconfiy, then you sleep, then you deiconify, all without giving the event loop a chance to respond. While the `sleep` command is running *no* events are processed. So, when you wake from sleep, the system hides the window, and then microseconds later it redraws it.

What is probably happening on windows is that the window manager is getting the iconfiy command and removing the window without tkinter's involvement. In other words, tkinter doesn't actually do anything to make it go away. On X11-based systems, however, this is all managed by the event loop.

If you want the window to go away, and a second later reappear, use the event loop to your advantage. Allow the event loop to update the screen, and arrange for the deiconify to happen at sometime in the future. For example:

```
def close_handler(self):
    self.root.iconify()
    self.after(1000, self.root.deiconify)
```

This should work on all platforms. It allows the event loop to respond to the iconify event, and then a second later the deiconify command will run.

Comment: the after() method works on windows, though a little deferrent from sleep(), but it does not work as expected on ubuntu.

Comment: @metaphy: you have to be more specific. What does "doesn't work" mean? What are you seeing?

Comment: on ubuntu, after closing the window, it icoinfies to the launcher, but it will not show again, seems deiconify() not working.