# Tkinter - How to close one window whilst opening another window in Tkinter - Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, authentication, window, ttk

I am extremely new to Tkinter and must use this for my programming coursework, i am looking for help to understand how to I destroy/hide the LoginWindow when the SuccessfulLogin window is opened. Bear in mind that i am new to tkinter. Thank you.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
```

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
class loginWindow():


def __init__(self, master): #constructor

    self.master = master
    self.master.title("Main Menu") #window title
    self.master.geometry("400x400") #window size
    self.master.configure(background = "#fff1d0") #window colour, hexadecimal codes

    #self.photo = PhotoImage(file = "filename.png") #sets up image
    #self.photoLabel = Label(self.master, image = self.photo, bg = "red") #puts image on label
    #self.photoLabel.place(x=350 y=600) #places onto the screen with specified coordinates

    self.enterLabel = tkinter.Label(self.master, text = "Launcher", font = ("Helvetica", 16), bg = "#fff1d0")
    self.enterLabel.pack(pady = 10)

    self.emptySpace = tkinter.Label(self.master, text = " ", bg = "#fff1d0")
    self.emptySpace.pack(pady = 10)

    self.username = tkinter.Label(self.master, text = "Username:", bg = "#fff1d0") #Label widget and properties
    self.username.pack()
    self.enterUser = tkinter.ttk.Entry(self.master, width = 40) #Creates text entry widget
    self.enterUser.pack()

    self.password = tkinter.Label(self.master, text = "Password:", bg = "#fff1d0") #Label widget and properties
    self.password.pack()
    self.enterPass = tkinter.ttk.Entry(self.master, width = 40, show = "*") #Creates text entry widget
    self.enterPass.pack()

    self.loginButton = tkinter.ttk.Button(self.master, width = 40, text = "Login", command = self.loginAccess)
    self.loginButton.pack(pady = 10)


def loginAccess(self):

    username = "Aaron" #Needs to become a dictionary or database  or something with all usernames and passwords
    password = "Password"
    global userUsername
    userUsername = self.enterUser.get()
    userPassword = self.enterPass.get()

    if userUsername != username and userPassword != password:

         self.enterLabel.configure(text = "Invalid username and password. Please try again.", font = (10))
         self.enterUser.delete(0, "end")
         self.enterPass.delete(0, "end")

    if userUsername == username and userPassword != password:

        self.enterLabel.configure(text="Invalid password. Please try again.", font = (10))
        self.enterPass.delete(0, "end")

    if userUsername == username and userPassword == password:

        self.enterUser.delete(0, "end")
        self.enterPass.delete(0, "end")
        self.goToSuccessfulLoginWindow()

def goToSuccessfulLoginWindow(self):

    root2 = tkinter.Toplevel()
    myGUI = successfulLogin(root2)
    myGUI.setName(userUsername)
```

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
class successfulLogin():


def __init__(self, master):

    self.master = master
    self.master.title("Login Successful")
    self.master.geometry("700x700")
    self.master.configure(background="#fff1d0")

    self.confirmLabel = tkinter.Label(self.master, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 16), bg = "#fff1d0")
    self.confirmLabel.pack()

    self.quitButton = tkinter.ttk.Button(self.master, text = "Quit", command = self.quitWindow)
    self.quitButton.pack()

    self.logOutButton = tkinter.ttk.Button(self.master, text = "Log out", command = self.logout)
    self.logOutButton.pack()

def setName(self, username):
    name = username
    self.confirmLabel.configure(text = "welcome " + name)

def quitWindow(self):
    self.master.quit()

def logout(self):
    loginWindow(root)
    self.master.destroy()
```

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
def centerWindow(width=300, height=200):
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))


root = tkinter.Tk()
centerWindow(310, 375)
root.resizable(False,False)
loginWindow(root)
root.mainloop(
```

Comment: the indentation in your code needs to be fixed. Also, you've posted way too much code. If your question is about how to manage two different windows, you probably only need a dozen or two lines of code to illustrate the problem you're having. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is a lot of unneeded code here in your question. Give us the code which is directly linked to your question.

Comment: Also - something simple like `if login == True, Then destroy LoginWindow And DrawNewWindow` will do the trick. Hopefully this pseudo code will help(?)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18548800/7032856) example below can be produced.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

#In order to hide main window
root.withdraw()

tk.Label(root, text="This is the main window").pack()

aWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)

def change_window():
    #remove the other window entirely
    aWindow.destroy()

    #make root visible again
    root.iconify()
    root.deiconify()

tk.Button(aWindow, text="This is aWindow", command=change_window).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In the example first there's a window `aWindow`, and when you click the button on it, it destroys `aWindow` and makes the `root` window visible again.